# 'EduRoster.Read.All' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationroot-list-schools?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), EduRoster.Read.All, EduRoster.ReadWrite.All are able to be assigned as Application permissions. I've added EduRoster.Read.All and granted it admin permissions in AAD App Registrations.

When I change the scope in my token request (tried in Postman and making a custom connector) to include EduRoster.Read.All, I get the error in the title. If I change the scope to .default, I don't get the error when requesting the token but I get "Required scp claim values are not provided." in the response.  I can assign EduRoster.ReadBasic as a delegated permission and I'm able to use either EduRoster.ReadBasic or .default as the scope and don't get any errors and the response is 200.

I'm pretty new to this stuff so I want to make sure that I'm not missing anything before I assume that  EduRoster.Read.All, EduRoster.ReadWrite.All aren't actually working for application permissions.

Comment: How are you obtaining your token?

Comment: This question led me down the right path. Now I'll try to answer this question correctly. 

I was able to get working in Postman using [a POST to /token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token) and [using an implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). Can't get it working with a Custom Connector. I try to change the Swagger file to implicit but when I save, it overwrites it. I suppose I could create a separate custom connector just to get the token. 

Thanks for your help.